# highcharts categories issues

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for a project which brings a mysql recordset.
I have two things i can't find the solution:

1. values are always form 3000 to 8000, how can i show 3000, 3500, 4000 and so on on the x axis?
2. the chart allows me to zoom in, and I'd like to show the y axis no matter the zoom level, is there a way?

here is my code:

```
var SpectrumName = '<?php echo $SpectrumName; ?>';
var SpectrumDate = '<?php echo $SpectrumDate; ?>';
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
   size:[ 400,250 ],
  chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     zoomType: 'xy',
     defaultSeriesType: 'line',
     marginRight: 130,
     marginBottom: 50,

  },
  title: {
     text: 'AstroSpec Observation of: ' + SpectrumName,
     x: -20 //center
  },
  subtitle: {
     text: 'Acquired on: ' + SpectrumDate,
     x: -20
  },
  xAxis: {
     categories: [<?php echo $x_colf1; ?>],
     labels: {
         formatter: function() {
             if (this.index % 500) { // even numbers only
                 return this.value;
             } else {
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }

  },

  yAxis: {min: 0,
     title: {
        text: ''
     },
     plotLines: [{
        value: 30,
        width: 3,
        color: '#808080'
     }]
  },
  plotOptions: {
      series: {
          enableMouseTracking: false,
          marker: {
              enabled: false
          }
      }
  },

  legend: {
     layout: 'vertical',
     align: 'right',
     verticalAlign: 'top',
     x: -10,
     y: 100,
     borderWidth: 0
  },
  series: [{
     name: 'R',
     data: [<?php echo $y_axis; ?>]
  }]
 });


});
```

Comment: For requirement number 2, are you looking for something like this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For # 1, try setting `min` and `tickInterval` as follows:

```
xAxis: {
    min: 3000,
    tickInterval: 500
}
```

I did not quite get the requirement # 2.